# Scikit Learn - Extract word tokens from a string delimiter using CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have list of strings. If any string contains the *'#'* character then I want to extract the first part of the string and get the frequency count of word tokens from this part of string only. i.e
if the string is *"first question # on stackoverflow"*
expected tokens are *"first","question"*

If the string does not contain *'#'* then return tokens of the whole string.

To compute the term document matrix I am using `CountVectorizer` from scikit.

Find below my code:

```
class MyTokenizer(object):
    def __call__(self,s):
        if(s.find('#')==-1):
            return s
        else:
            return s.split('#')[0]
    def FindKmeans():
        text = ["first ques # on stackoverflow", "please help"]
        vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=MyTokenizer(), analyzer = 'word')
        pos_vector = vec.fit_transform(text).toarray()
        print(vec.get_feature_names())`

output : [u' ', u'a', u'e', u'f', u'h', u'i', u'l', u'p', u'q', u'r', u's', u't', u'u']

Expected Output : [u'first', u'ques', u'please', u'help']
```

Comment: Do you want to count the occurence of `first` `ques` if the line contains `#` in the whole document or just to show those words which have `#`?

Comment: i want to count the occurrence of tokens of the substring if the line contains # as well as the occurrence of tokens from the whole string if it does contain #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lays with your tokenizer, you've split the string into the bits you want to keep and the bits you don't want to keep, but you've not split the string into words.
Try using the tokenizer below

```
class MyTokenizer(object):
    def __call__(self,s):
        if(s.find('#')==-1):
            return s.split(' ')
        else:
            return s.split('#')[0].split(' ')
```

Comment: thanks, it worked.  I see, instead of returning the string i should return the list of tokens, after all it is a tokenizer. But when i returned string from custom tokenizer it overrides the string tokenization step. So, instead of tokenizing on characters it should have generated ['first ques', 'please help'].

Answer (score 6):

You could split on your separator(`#`) at most once and take the first part of the split.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def tokenize(text):
    return([text.split('#', 1)[0].strip()])

text = ["first ques # on stackoverflow", "please help"]

vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)
data = vec.fit_transform(text).toarray()
vocab = vec.get_feature_names()

required_list = []
for word in vocab:
    required_list.extend(word.split())
print(required_list)

#['first', 'ques', 'please', 'help']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 s.split('#',1)[0]
```

`#` is your result. you dont need check that "#" is exist or not.